# Unit tests working well with maven but won't run when using them with IntelliJ

Tags: scala, maven, intellij-idea, scalatest

I have some unit tests in a Scala project that are working fine when using mvn clean test to run them (scalatest-maven-plugin version 1.0).

However, when I try to use IntelliJ UI to run them I get this error:

```
objc[56331]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java (0x10f8774c0) and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib (0x1102d24e0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ERROR: -r has been deprecated for a very long time and is no longer supported, to prepare for reusing it for a different purpose in the near future. Please change all uses of -r to -C.
    at org.scalatest.tools.ArgsParser$.checkArgsForValidity(ArgsParser.scala:41)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter(Runner.scala:857)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.run(Runner.scala:850)
    at org.scalatest.tools.Runner.run(Runner.scala)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.ScalaTestRunner.runScalaTest2(ScalaTestRunner.java:131)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.ScalaTestRunner.main(ScalaTestRunner.java:28)
```

Probably it has something to do with a dependency that I have in the pom. It is a dependency to an artifact that I have developed in a separated project. If I remove that dependency, this error disappears.

I need that dependency and I cannot figure out what is wrong with it. Maven is working just fine but I would like to have access to the debugger in IntelliJ.

Any suggestions? I have run out of ideas now and Google is not giving me anything useful so far.

Also, other colleagues are experiencing the same, so I doubt it has something to do with my local configuration.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you able to post a repro?

Comment: Sadly, no. Since i am not able to identify which part is causing it and cannot share company code... The command line executed by IntellyJ: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java "-javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=64581:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "<jars-removed-for-simplicity>" org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.ScalaTestRunner -s mypackage.myclass -C org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.ScalaTestReporter -showProgressMessages true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "scalatest" library does not like the way that IntelliJ is invoking it.

Try updating your Scala plugin in IntelliJ?

#### UPDATE:

I have done some digging in the source code of IntelliJ and Scalatest (both can be seen in the stack trace you showed above):

1) Scalatest rejects this "-r" arg that IntelliJ is passing it here:

https://github.com/scalatest/scalatest/blob/b97f944f4a2690744c26dc875097407baba7e21d/scalatest/src/main/scala/org/scalatest/tools/ArgsParser.scala#L41

2) The IntelliJ code which passes arg "-r" is here:

https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-scala/blob/88317c1dd8a8cd6b8578adc17c1ead36a2a5a77a/scala/runners/src/org/jetbrains/plugins/scala/testingSupport/scalaTest/ScalaTestRunner.java#L131

Notice that this is not the latest version of the IntelliJ scala plugin.

Interestingly, the "-r" arg is only passed if this code has set `isOlderScalaTestVersion` true (see line 94), which appears to be if the detected ScalaTest version is 1.x (see line 261)

So my current guess (without the benefit of a repro case) is that something about your linked library is causing IntelliJ Scala plugin to think that you are using ScalaTest 1.x, but actually you are using ScalaTest 3.x? Does the linked library have a transitive dependency on an old ScalaTest?

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I have update Scala plugin to v2019.1.8. In fact, i had already updated the whole IntelliJ version to the latest one hoping to solve the issue... No luck so far. Thanks anyway for the suggestion.

Comment: Just to add something, I am not sure it is the way intellij invokes scalatest, since It is working for other projects (and also for this one if the mentioned dependency is removed).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the resources, they are being really helpful. I think the error is in the line: `String version = jar.getManifest().getMainAttributes().getValue("Bundle-Version");` in `isOlderScalaTestVersion()` method. `version` is evaluated to `null` and then a `-r` option is added in `runScalaTest1` and/or `runScalaTest2`. I will keep trying to figure out why that is being evaluated to `null`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! You where right, the 'version' was null because I had a dependency that already included scalatest artifact. I have change the code in that project to use scalatest with `<scope>test</scope>` in the pom.xml and not it works perfectly.